# sql addition of 2 queries return NULL

Tags: sql

I want to make an addition of the sum of two queries (please see my queries below, these examples works). My problem is when one of the queries return a null result like

```
select (select sum(60+3+25+2))+(select sum(0)) as montant
```

the result of the addition is automatically NULL.
But when the 2 queries have results more than null like:

```
select (select sum(60+3+25+2))+(select sum(300+50)) as montant
```

the addition works and i get the right result:

here is the first query that gives me 90 as a result

```
select sum(lf.quantite) from fraisforfait f  
        inner join lignefraisforfait lf on lf.idFraisForfait = f.id 
        inner join fichefrais ff on ff.idVisiteur = lf.idVisiteur and ff.mois = lf.mois 
        where lf.idVisiteur = "a131" and lf.mois = "201312"
```

here is the second one that gives me 0 as a result

```
select sum(lfh.montant) 
        from lignefraishorsforfait lfh 
        inner join fichefrais ff on ff.idVisiteur = lfh.idVisiteur and ff.mois = lfh.mois 
        where ff.idVisiteur = "a131" and ff.mois = "201312"
```

here is the addition of the 2 queries that gives me a NULL result, but i expect 90:

```
 select (select sum(lf.quantite) from fraisforfait f  
        inner join lignefraisforfait lf on lf.idFraisForfait = f.id 
        inner join fichefrais ff on ff.idVisiteur = lf.idVisiteur and ff.mois = lf.mois 
        where lf.idVisiteur = "a131" and lf.mois = "201401") + (select sum(lfh.montant) 
        from lignefraishorsforfait lfh 
        inner join fichefrais ff on ff.idVisiteur = lfh.idVisiteur and ff.mois = lfh.mois 
        where ff.idVisiteur = "a131" and ff.mois = "201401") as montantValide;
```

Does anyone has a solution to this problem? thanks for your time.

Comment: `sum()` is an aggregate function which is used to add values from column in different *rows*. Therefor `sum(60+3+25+2)` does not make any sense.

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add something that will turn your `NULL` in to a `0`.

```
select COALESCE(sum(lfh.montant), 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this.

t-sql

```
select (select 1 value) + isnull((select null value),0);
```

mysql

```
select (select 1 value) + ifnull((select null value),0);
```

Comment: Like @MatBailie mentioned you need to cater for the NULL although I prefer ifnull if you are only working with a single value.

Comment: Do you mean `ISNULL`?  And it's worth mentioning that this is T-SQL specific, it won't work in MySQL for example.

Comment: Apologies ... yes for t-sql it's isnull - adjusted for t-sql.

Comment: `NVL` works the same for Oracle, and my MySQL is pretty rusty and not very extensive but I thought `IFNULL` was more or less equivalent?

Comment: Just thought I would point out that I don't see anything t-sql specific in this question. Going to include mysql version as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can write it like this

```
select isnull((select isnull(sum(60+3+25+2),0))+(select isnull(sum(0),0)),0) 
as montant
```

Comment: `ISNULL` assumes T-SQL; this won't work in MySQL or other RDBMS.

Answer (score 0):

you can use **ISNULL** Function in sum function like this

```
select Sum(ISNULL(value,0)) as result
```

so if the value is null it return secend argument and sum function will return proper result

Comment: `ISNULL` assumes T-SQL; this won't work in MySQL or other RDBMS.  Also, putting the `ISNULL()` inside the `SUM()` can cause un-necessary additional CPU load, unlike using `ISNULL(SUM(), 0)`.